# Terminal does not show yargs' handler value

Tags: node.js, terminal, command, yargs

I am learning node.js and I have first problem. After I have installed yargs and I am trying to create yargs command but it does not show in the terminal. When I type `node app.js mycommand` in terminal it only returns me the array of args, not my command, but if I type 'node app.js --help' it returns each command. Am I doing something wrong?

```
const yargs = require('yargs')

 yargs.command({
     command: 'mycommand',
     describe: 'mydesc',
     handler: () => { console.log('some text') } })
```

I would like to have my console.log displays 'some text' when I type `'node app.js mycommand'` but actually I have only array of args:

> { _: [ 'mycommand' ], '$0': 'app.js' }

Answer (score 0):

You should add `.parse()` to the end of your code. That is all.

```
const yargs = require('yargs')

 yargs.command({
     command: 'mycommand',
     describe: 'mydesc',
     handler: () => { console.log('some text') } }).parse()
```

If you have too many commands like this, instead of using parse() for each command, just type this below your code:

```
yargs.parse()
```

Or type this below your code

```
console.log(yargs.argv)
```

However this will also  print out the "argv" (arguments vector).

Answer (score 0):

Either use `yargs.argv;` or `.parse()`

```
yargs.command({
  command: 'add',
  describe: 'This is add param',
  handler: function() {
    console.log("This is add notes command ");
  }
});
yargs.argv;
```

or

```
yargs.command({
  command: 'add',
  describe: 'This is add param',
  handler: function() {
    console.log("This is add notes command ");
  }
}).parse();
```

to run it...

node app.js add

Answer (score 0):

Your code is write only. But you are not displaying the commands. That's the reason you are not seeing anything. You can fix this in two ways.

1. `console.log(yargs.argv)`
2. `yargs.parse()`

either of these should be added after finishing your code.

PS: If you use `console.log(yargs.argv)` , argv object will be printed along with your desired result.

If still getting confused, feel free to check below code

```
const yargs = require('yargs');

 yargs.command({
     command: 'mycommand',
     describe: 'mydesc',
     handler: () => { console.log('some text') } 
    });

yargs.parse();
```